# journald RuntimeMaxUse is ignored, quota tied to RuntimeMaxFileSize instead

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald, journalctl

## Setup

Using systemd 244 (244.5+) on kernel 4.19.62.

I want to set the total journal storage size to 100MB. Journald is set to volatile storage, so logs end up on `/run/log/journal/...` and **RuntimeMaxUse** should be used to set the storage quota as follows in **/etc/systemd/journald.conf**:

```
[Journal]
Storage=volatile
RuntimeMaxUse=100M
RuntimeMaxFileSize=2M
```

By tweaking these config values, the journal log size and quota do change and startup messages in journalctl also show change.

Between config value changes, I stop systemd-journald.service, delete all `system*` files under `/run/log/journal/...` and restart the service.

**NOTE:** when `Storage=persistent` and logs use `/var/log/journal/`, the equivalent **SystemMaxUse** is respected correctly. This appears to only be a bug in volatile/RuntimeMaxUse.

## Observed bug

The Runtime**MaxUse** (100M) is ignored. The journal quota is set to **64MB** so long as Runtime**MaxFileSize** is less than 32M.

If Runtime**MaxFileSize** is set to more than 32M, the journal quota is set to double that value.

Runtime**MaxUse** appears to be ignored in both cases.

Is this a bug in journald/systemd config handling? Why is Runtime**MaxUse** ignored, and a value of 64M or double Runtime**MaxFileSize** used as the journal quota instead?

I see there are a couple of places in the journald source where max_use can be set to double max_size:

- https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v244/src/journal/journal-file.c#L3747
- https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v244/src/journal/journal-file.c#L3772

## Bug examples

With `RuntimeMaxUse=100M` and `RuntimeMaxFileSize=2M` a quota of 64M (instead of my requested 100M) is set, as seen in the journal startup messages:

```
systemd-journald[20312]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/...) is 2.0M, max 64.0M, 62.0M free.
-- Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/...) is currently using 2.0M.
-- Maximum allowed usage is set to 64.0M.
-- Leaving at least 1.5G free (of currently available 31.2G of disk space).
-- Enforced usage limit is thus 64.0M, of which 62.0M are still available.
```

Using `RuntimeMaxUse=100M` and `RuntimeMaxFileSize=31M`, 64M still used:

```
systemd-journald[20989]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/...) is 8.0M, max 64.0M, 56.0M free.
-- Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/...) is currently using 8.0M.
-- Maximum allowed usage is set to 64.0M.
-- Leaving at least 1.5G free (of currently available 31.2G of disk space).
-- Enforced usage limit is thus 64.0M, of which 56.0M are still available.
```

Using `RuntimeMaxUse=100M` and `RuntimeMaxFileSize=33M`, the quota ends up 66M:

```
systemd-journald[21557]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/...) is 8.0M, max 66.0M, 58.0M free.
-- Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/...) is currently using 8.0M.
-- Maximum allowed usage is set to 66.0M.
-- Leaving at least 1.5G free (of currently available 31.2G of disk space).
-- Enforced usage limit is thus 66.0M, of which 58.0M are still available.
```

Using `RuntimeMaxUse=100M` and `RuntimeMaxFileSize=200M` we break past the 100M limit, with 400M seemingly coming from double the RuntimeMaxFileSize of 200M:

```
systemd-journald[25271]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/...) is 8.0M, max 400.0M, 392.0M free.
-- Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/...) is currently using 8.0M.
-- Maximum allowed usage is set to 400.0M.
-- Leaving at least 1.5G free (of currently available 31.2G of disk space).
-- Enforced usage limit is thus 400.0M, of which 392.0M are still available.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 64M was coming from an additional config file I was unaware of: `/lib/systemd/journald.conf.d/00-systemd-conf.conf`.

With that additional setting of `RuntimeMaxUse=64M` removed, I can now set the desired values in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`.

Tip: use strace on journald startup to see what config files it really uses and which order they are read in. This is how the `/lib` config file was finally revealed.